# register function for all urls in flask

Tags: python, function, url, view, flask

HI i have a function in my views file which i need to be use in my header file , which is common to all templates ,

```
@app.route('/admin/')   
def adminhome():
    row1 =''
    try:
        db = connect_db()
        rows=g.db.query("SELECT * FROM `auth_user` order by id DESC ")
        rows1 = list(rows)
        data=''
        if len(rows1) > 0:
            users = rows1
        #close_db(db)
    except Exception as e:
        users = e   

    return render_template('admin/index.html',users=users)
```

but this function just works for

> @app.route('/admin/')

how can i register this function for all urls

Comment: Did you try with @app.route('/')

Comment: You mean that this function should be available in all templates?

Comment: yes exactly what i need because a header file will be included to all my templates

Comment: According to the title, you should check this snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try app.context_processor: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors

Example:

```
def adminhome():
    row1 =''
    try:
        db = connect_db()
        rows=g.db.query("SELECT * FROM `auth_user` order by id DESC ")
        rows1 = list(rows)
        data=''
        if len(rows1) > 0:
            users = rows1
        #close_db(db)
    except Exception as e:
        users = e
    return users

@app.context_processor
def inject():
    return dict(adminhome=adminhome)
```

With this adminhome is available in all your templates, which returns 'users' and you can render the 'users' in the way you want.

Hope it helps..

Comment: acctually i am new to flask and when i use the   adminhome   in my template file i got   something like this   <function test at 0xb7151e2c>

Comment: Its a function object, Just call it as adminhome()

Comment: do youmean i have to use this in templates like adminhome()

Comment: ya.. In jinja2, you call functions.

Comment: but when i use this as you said it print the same way adminhome()   as text in template

Comment: Try: {{ adminhome() }}. Jinja2 evaluate variables inside {{ some_var }}.

Comment: yes it works like this , but can you please tell me if a function has multiple variables than how we will use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33757/discussion-between-rohit-goel-and-rajpy)

Comment: return multiple values and iterate over it in template. Eg: In adminhome() function 'return users, teams'. In template do: {% for i in adminhome() %}.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make this function a decorator and then use it in your other view functions,. E.g. this is part of my solution to this problem (not perfect! this is just a fragment):

```
def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped():
        if "username" in session:
            return func()
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('startpage'))
    return wrapped


 @app.route('/admin/')   
 @login_required
 def adminhome():
       return render_template('admin/index.html',users=users)


@app.route("/hello_world")
@login_required
def hello():
     return "hello world"
```

Note that this is not a one to one ready made example. I'm just giving you a pattern of using it, you have to figure it out for yourself, I recommend that you start by reading the [relevant portion of documentation of Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/)